# True Mobile Rendition of Documents in Box View

Tags: box-view-api

Box is great but on a mobile device, it simply scales down the SVG size, requiring zooming and panning for the document to be read. It would be great to have a responsive rendition viz: separate the graphics from text, yet keep them in the right sequential order. For the graphics, allow zooming and for the text, enlarge and wrap around the viewport so it can easily be read, yet retaining all markup like bold, italics, underline etc.

Are there functions in viewer.js which permit recognizing these individual document components and thus their manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

Viewer.js does not offer this functionality currently, but this is definitely something on our long term backlog. I agree that it would be very nice to have a reflowable layout for mobile devices, but this would likely involve extra work on the conversion side. You can submit feature requests to view-api-features@box.com for ideas/features like this.